# Results based on column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

This is in SQL Server. Table 1 has two columns, Column1 and Column2 and Column1 is part of the composite key. Column1 can be associated to more than one value of column2.

Something like this:

```
Column1 | Column2
---------------------
value1  | Value20
Value1  | Value21
Value1  | Value22
```

Query result should be based on whether value1 is associated to value20 or not.
If value1 is associated to value20 it should return row2 and row3, otherwise return nothing.

I tried joining the table by it self, but I am not able to get the end result I need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE1 T2 ON T1.COLUMN1 = T2.COLUMN1
WHERE T1.COLUMN2 IN (VALUE20)
  AND T2.COLUMN2 IN (VALUE21, VALUE22);
```

I can not use union here as there are other tables involved in the query to return other values.

Comment: You should always include your rdbms `SQL Server` or `MySQL` get different sintaxis

Comment: It is SQL server, will update the question as well, thanks.

Comment: Just edit the question and include the `tag` that way you get attention of the right users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH candidates AS (
SELECT Column1, Column2
  FROM Table1
  WHERE Column2 = 'Value20'
)
SELECT t.Column1, t.Column2
  FROM Table1 t
  JOIN candidates c ON (c.Column1 = t.Column1 AND t.Column2 <> 'Value20')
```

Comment: Thank you.  It should be   
t.Column2 <> 'Value20' and select should have Column2 as well in 'with'.

Comment: Updated the response.  Thanks.